# Container auto exited after docker run

Tags: dockerfile

Can somone help me? why my Dockerfile status exited after processing CMD line
here is my Dockerfile

FROM centos:7
RUN yum install gcc readline-devel zlib-devel -y
RUN yum install nano mlocate -y && updatedb
RUN yum install make -y

COPY postgresql-15.1.tar.gz /
RUN tar -zxvf postgresql-15.1.tar.gz

WORKDIR  postgresql-15.1
RUN ./configure
RUN make
RUN make install

RUN useradd -r postgres
RUN chown -R postgres:postgres /usr/local/pgsql/

USER postgres
RUN /usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data

CMD ["/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl", "-D", "/usr/local/pgsql/data","start"]